# How to do mapping with the entityclass from Dto class and also using repository to do this,but I am not getting it

Tags: java, spring-boot, dictionary

This is my dto class and I try to map the field of entity becuse I want to use that in the service layer.

> Blockquote

```
package com.prolifics.dto;


import java.util.Map;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class FacilityDTO {
    private Integer id;

    private String city;
    
    private String name;

    private String pin;
    
    private String state;

    private String status;
    private float lattitude;

    private float longitude;
    
    private Map<String,Integer> vaccineStock;
    

    public Map<String, Integer> getVaccineStock() {
        return vaccineStock;
    }

    public void setVaccineStock(Map<String, Integer> vaccineStock) {
        this.vaccineStock = vaccineStock;
    }

    public float getLattitude() {
        return lattitude;
    }

    public void setLattitude(float lattitude) {
        this.lattitude = lattitude;
    }

    public float getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(float longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPin() {
        return pin;
    }

    public void setPin(String pin) {
        this.pin = pin;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    
}
```

In my facilityVaccineEntity there is a stock variable of int type  and I want to map that field in my dto class as it does not contain stock field so that I can access it from service class. how to do this?

```
@Repository
public interface FacilityVaccineRepository extends CrudRepository<FacilityVaccine,Integer>{
     
    public FacilityVaccine stock(int stock);

}
```